# Filtering Boolean in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, boolean

I have a df with ±100k rows and 10 columns.
I would like to find/filter which rows contain at least 2 to 4 True values.
For simplicity's sake, let's say I have this df:

```
 A   B     C     D     E     F
 1  True  True  False False True  
 2  False True  True  True  False 
 3  False False False False False  
 4  True  False False False True  
 5  True  False False False False
```

Expected output:

```
A   B     C     D     E     F
1  True  True  False False True  
2  False True  True  True  False 
4  True  False False False True
```

I have tried using

```
df[(df['B']==True) | (df['C']==True) | (df['D']==True)| (df['E']==True)| (df['F']==True)]
```

But this only eliminates False rows and doesn't work if I want to find instances of at least 2/3 True.

Can anyone please help? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for only boolean columns, count `True`s by `sum` and then filter values by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df  = df[df.select_dtypes(bool).sum(axis=1).between(2,4)]
print (df)
   A      B      C      D      E      F
0  1   True   True  False  False   True
1  2  False   True   True   True  False
3  4   True  False  False  False   True
```

Comment: Where have you defined boolean? 'bool' should do there